# RPi.GPIO autocompletion

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

Is there any way to have auto-completion when working with the RPi.GPIO in Python? I don't see it having any Python sources that could be used for it.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, which uses PyCharm's plugins.

Comment: what are you using to code? PyCharm IDE allows this (if I'm understanding what you're asking)

Comment: I use IDEA for my Perl programming. I'll test it out here with that and compare to PyCharm

Comment: Thanks, that would be helpful :) . In any case, I wonder from where PyCharm pulls data for auto completion, because RPi.GPIO have mostly binary data/C code.

Comment: it definitely works for me on idea 2016.2.2 after installing the Python plugin. after I `import RPi.GPIO as gpio`, I get the full list of available methods/attributes that I can select from/autocomplete

Comment: ...I think I lied. I'm going to test on pycharm to see if it acts differently